# Convert from varchar(50) to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have imported csv file to sql server manager. one of column is date but his data type is vachar(50).

I used the basic (cast, convert, try_parse) but still get message:

> (Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.)

could you please help me :)

```
select cast(
    replace(
        case
            when [factuur_datum] in ('null','')
                then null
            else [factuur_datum]
                end, '-','') as date) as [factuur_datum]
from [dbo].[verkoop]
```

Comment: mysql or sqlserver ???'

Comment: Please show an example of your text date format.

Comment: text date format is like: 20-12-2018

Comment: I am using sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below query to convert it into date

```
convert(date,'20-12-2018',105)
```

Comment: @MoslehAlnaqeeb, I'm glad you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.

Comment: @MoslehAlnaqeeb glad that it helped :) .Please mark this as an answer so others can benefit from it too.

Answer (score 0):

I take it **factuur_datum** is the date column:

```
select
cast(factuur_datum as date) as [Alias]
from [dbo].[verkoop]
```

Not sure what the data looks like so can you include an example?

EDIT

```
convert(datetime,'factuur_datum',1)
```

possibly will error out if there are null values so you may need to case out the nulls then convert.

Comment: Also you may want to case it in one query and then make the case a sub query, then cast on the case alias

Comment: here is an example (column name is: Factuur_datum) and the data (01-12-2018)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you intend:

```
select try_cast(replace(factuur_datum, '-', '') as date) as factuur_datum
from [dbo].[verkoop]
```

Non-dates will result in `NULL`.